# Do bitcoins count as income in the UK?

Tags: mining-reward, legal, taxes, united-kingdom

I am interested in mining bitcoin here in the UK. I have done a quick search and cannot find anything relevant. If I were to use a cloud mining service to mine bitcoin, would it be counted as income AND/or would it have to be taxed?

Could a link also be posted so I can see more information on it please?